# Tool to view .evtx Windows event log files

Tags: windows, gratis, parser

A client sent me some .evtx event log export files. I'm looking for a free viewer with filter/query capabilities.

- I have looked at [NirSoft's MyEventViewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/my_event_viewer.html) with its `/LoadFiles` option, but from the documentation it's unclear whether that loads the files *into* the log files, which I definitely don't want (the comment that I have to *specify the appropriate log type name* makes me suspicious). It also talks only about .evt files, not .evtx. If anyone can confirm that it does not load the files into the system logs, I can investigate it further. (I have sent them a mail, <s>but no response yet</s> see accepted answer).
- [Windows Event Viewer Plus](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-event-viewer-plus-v-1-0-released) cannot load files
- [EvtLogParser](https://martin77s.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/evtlogparser/) comes close. It is handy for querying, but has no 'view all' mode where you can just browse through the file unfiltered. At a minimum I have to select the event type (error, warning, information...) so it is workable, but maybe there's something better.
- [Event Log Explorer](http://eventlogxp.com/features.html) has everything I like, but it only has a free version for personal use
- [MS Log Parser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) is a command-line tool ;-)

Comment: No GUI but the python-evtx library can parse your error logs into ASCII XML. https://github.com/williballenthin/python-evtx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to my query Nirsoft updated their MyEventViewer (which only reads the old style .evt levent log files) and published [FullEventLogView v1.00](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html).

> FullEventLogView is a simple tool for Windows 10/8/7/Vista that displays in a table the details of all events from the event logs of Windows, including the event description. It allows you to view the events of your local computer, events of a remote computer on your network, and events stored in .evtx files. It also allows you to export the events list to text/csv/tab-delimited/html/xml file from the GUI and from command-line.

Selecting the source:

[image]

Filtering is then done in the Advanced Options:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to my other answer, I found out by accident:

You can just double click a .evtx file and it will open in the Windows Event Log Viewer in a separate *Saved logs* folder:

[image]

So there is no danger of overwriting or merging with your own event logs (that's what prompted me to write the question).

Answer (score 0):

[Gigasheet](https://gigasheet.co) is a free, online cybersecurity data analysis tool. You can open EVTX files in a spreadsheet-like interface that supports searching, filtering, and segmenting large EVTX files. You can upload files up to 10GB for free and export files as a CSV. Full disclosure: I'm co-founder at Gigasheet.

More details about the EVTX viewer here: https://www.gigasheet.co/post/online-evtx-parser-and-viewer

Comment: Welcome Jason!  Our community requires *full* disclosure of any affiliation with software you recommend.  Please edit your post to include your affiliation with the software you are recommending.  Thanks!